# How to get current iframe url in a javascript var

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hello guys i kind of a javascript newbie.
Here is my problem

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <iframe name='frmExternal' id='frmExternal' src='www.dynamically-changing-url.com'></frame>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the current url in the iframe where the user browse along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   document.getElementsByName('frmExternal')[0].src
```

Comment: could you plz put the codes together with a alert button that alert the current url.. Newbie here.

Comment: alert(//Your code here). There's a difference between newbie and lazy